# Display my site name before category/post name

Tags: php, laravel

I have the code below that works fine, but it shows up "category/post - my site name"

```
@section('head_title', $post->title .' - '.getcong('sitename') )
```

Now when i want to do like this "my site name - category/post" it's simple logic 
it should be like this

```
@section(getcong('sitename') .' - '.'head_title', $post->title )
```

But the problem is that it shows error, any idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IT's really simple. `head_title` is the section name, so it has to be like this:

```
@section('head_title', getcong('sitename') .' - '. $post->title )
```

Comment: @highcode Please accept the answer if it was the right one :)